# Fluentd not able to access the logs present under /var/lib/docker/containers due to permission issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, fluentd

I am trying to read the container logs through fluentd and pass it to the elastic search. I have mounted the directories from the host onto fluentd container which include all symlinks and actual files.
But when I see the fluentd container logs , it say those logs, present under `/var/log/pods/` are unreadable. Then I manually navigated to the path under fluentd container where logs are present but unfortunately I got permission denied issue.
I went till `/var/lib/docker/containers` , then the permissions were 0700 and owner was root. Even I am trying to run my fluentd container by setting

`- name: FLUENT_UID
  value: "0"`

But still it is not able to read.

`volumes:
  - name: varlog
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/
   - name: varlibdockercontainers
     hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/docker/containers`

.....

`volumeMounts:
   - name: varlog
     mountPath: /var/log/
   - name: varlibdockercontainers
     mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers`

Comment: Can you post the whole fluentd deployment yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [security contexts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/). Among other things they allow you to specify the user that will run in the container with `runAsUser`, the primary group of that user with `runAsGroup`, and the volume owner with `fsGroup`.

Comment: Thanks @alassane , eventually I ended up doing same.

Comment: I am facing the Permission Denied error in filebeat pod in "/var/lib/docker/containers/fb384dd70af7e42a417e240d0dfd1075c541e4a76c6d1355d04199a4b7f7d95b" path even though am using SCC and "runAsUser: 0". Any suggestions please

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad im facing the same issue, found fix?